# Updating column based on columns from other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

folks!

I am fairly new to programming and I am trying to write an SQL statement that reference two separate tables - Organisation and User. I have been searching for answers, but I am unable to find any that works.

The intention of this statement is to update the status of the user only the following 2 conditions are satisfied;

- User's email, password, and activation code matches the database
- If the organisation the user is tied to is activated/approved

```
UPDATE User AS u 
SET u.isActivated =
CASE 
    WHEN (
        SELECT o.isApproved
        FROM Organisation AS o
        WHERE o.organisationId = (
             SELECT u.organisationID
             FROM User AS u
             WHERE u.email = " + email +"))
        = 'true' THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
WHERE u.email = " + email + "
AND u.password = " + password + " 
AND u.activationCode = " + activationCode + ";
```

Comment: Are you using parameters in your conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Use FROM in the [UPDATE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) to connect the tables:

```
UPDATE  User AS u 
SET     u.isActivated   = (o.isApproved = TRUE) -- will be TRUE or FALSE
FROM    
    Organisation AS o
WHERE   
    u.organisationID    = o.organisationId
AND u.email             = " + email + "
AND u.password          = " + password + " 
AND u.activationCode    = " + activationCode + ";
```

Offtopic, but really important: This piece of SQL smells like an opportunity for SQL injection, you're creating a string that will be executed as SQL. I really hope you got your security under control and use a secure method to put variables in your SQL

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! I will give an update when I try this out. And, thank you so much for your advice, Frank! 

I hope you have a pleasant week!